# How would I go about prewarming cache for Logged In users?

Tags: cache, login, full-page-cache

We have implemented a Full Page Cache extension as well as a redis backend for cache storage and session storage (separate redis instances). One issue we currently have is that although our basic cache warmer crawls and caches the pages for non logged in users, it doesn't cache it for logged in users.

Currently they way the FPC extension works for logged in users are:
1) User A logs in and visits a number of pages
2) User B logs in and when visiting same pages as User A it is served from Cache.

I am looking for some way that we can crawl and warm the cache for a few specific pages for logged in users (or a specific user group). The reason being some of our products are extremely complicated in terms of customization options so if Magento loads those pages without cache it can take up to 11 seconds versus with cache it's under 3 seconds. This problem is limited to a few products due to the complexity of the product.

Any suggestions or pointer in the right direction on how I could do this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What is the name of extension? Is it 3rd party ext?

In my practice I have faced with such problems with 3rd party FPC module. The issue appeared when page uploaded without magento instantiation. It means that cookie creation/instantiation/etc. was made also without magento.

Try to jump through pages and look if your cookie will be the same or not. Also pay your attention on cookie-domain value. Is it `.example.com` or just `example.com`

**upd.1**

I've never faced with that extension. I tried to find in reviews or in change log anything which refers to cookie or session, but didn't find anything. All reviews on connect are positive. Most probably your problem is caused by incompatibility with some another extension, installed on your host.

My pieces of advice:

- try to disable other extensions. Firstly disable extensions which are related to cookie / session / store management. And check
- as I told early try to jump through pages and check if customer cookie changed or not. Check cookie-domain or other settings in admin area.
- try to contact technical support of module vendor
- maybe you just disable the setting which allow cache by some condition (for example: disable ext. when customer logged in / added product to cart / visit some specific page)

Comment: Yes the extension is 3rd Party: Its Mirasvit Full Page Cache

Comment: In terms of the extension, apparently the manner in which the extension is currently functioning is how it is meant to work (when I contacted their support team) hence why I am looking for a solution to crawl a few specific  product pages as a logged in user.